# What are current values in PG admin configuration editor for postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, configuration, pgadmin

I am tuning a postgresql.conf file and here is what is shown in PG admin configuration editor

[image: configuration editor]

What does the current value corresponds to?
For the shared buffers (red line), what is the value there?

Comment: I think you should do this in the conf file directly.  Also, after logging into the DB, a `SHOW shared_buffers;` will show you the value in use.  If the question is what exactly 524288 means (if it is bytes, pages, etc.), please refer to the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-NAMES-VALUES - in the end, `SELECT unit FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'shared_buffers';` will show you the default unit.

Answer (score 2):

Current value is what the currently active database is using.

many of those settings require the database to be restarted (or reboot) before they take effect.